# N-epsilon proof that sequence converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Prove that this sequence converges to 27:
$$\{\frac{(n-1)(3n+1)^3}{(n-2)^4}\}$$
Here is my proof:

Want to show: $\forall\epsilon>0,\exists N > 0| \forall n \in \mathbb N, n>N \implies|\frac{(n-1)(3n+1)^3}{(n-2)^4}-27|<\epsilon$

$$|\frac{(n-1)(3n+1)^3}{(n-2)^4}-27|$$
$$<|\frac{n(3n+1)^3}{(n-2)^4}-27|$$
$$\text{... do some arithmetic for common denominator and simplification...}$$
$$=|\frac{243n^3-639n^2+865n-423}{n^4-8n^3+24n^2-32n+16}|$$

But then I'm stuck on this step. How can I simplify this so that I can choose a $N$ with respect to $\epsilon$?

Comment: You may want to consider doing some polynomial division to try to simplify the expression first

Comment: @JohnColtraneisJC That could be possible, but I don't see how it would help me

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to simplify, but rather to "majorate", note that:

Find a larger numerator:

1- If $n>0$
$$
243n^3−639n^2+865n−423<243n^3+865n
$$

2-if $n>\sqrt(865)$:
$$
n^3>865n
$$
Thus:
$$
243n^3−639n^2+865n−423<244n^3
$$

Find a smaller denominator:

For $n>0$:
$$
n^4−8n^3+24n^2−32n+16>n^4−8n^3−32n
$$

For $n>8$:
$$
n^4−8n^3−32n>n^4−9n^3
$$

So:
$$
\frac{243n^3−639n^2+865n−423}{n^4−8n^3+24n^2−32n+16}>\frac{244n^3}{n^4−9n^3}=\frac{244}{n−9}<\varepsilon
$$

Now it suffices to pick:
$$
n>244/\varepsilon+9
$$