# How to prove convergence for sequences?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

For this question, I know that the sequence converges, but I get stuck in the middle of the proof. Here is what I have so far. Can anyone please help me out?

Determine whether the sequence is convergent or divergent.

$$\left\{\frac{(n-1)(3n+1)^3}{(n-2)^4}\right\}$$

---

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{(n-1)(3n+1)^3}{(n-2)^4}\right) = 27$$

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. Suppose $n>N$

\begin{align}
|a_n-L|=&\; \left|\frac{(n-1)(3n+1)^3}{(n-2)^4}-27\right|
=&\; \left|\frac{(n-1)(3n+1)^3-27(n-2)^4}{(n-2)^4}\right|
\end{align}

Comment: Try multiplying out the numerator and see what cancel.

Comment: How do I expand the cube though?

Comment: Just foil it out.

Comment: You've asked five similar questions in five days about sequence convergence.  Have the answers to those questions proved useful?

Comment: They have been, but I'm just stuck on how to get further from this point.

Comment: Ok, after expanding it, what am I supposed to drop? can I drop multiple terms?

Answer (score 0):

This question is a [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2704821/n-epsilon-proof-that-sequence-converges/2704836#2704836). I'll answer again anyway.

The typical trick is to find upper or lower bounds for the terms involved:

Find a larger numerator:

1- If $n>0$
$$
243n^3−639n^2+865n−423<243n^3+865n
$$

2-if $n>\sqrt(865)$:
$$
n^3>865n
$$
Thus:
$$
243n^3−639n^2+865n−423<244n^3
$$

Find a smaller denominator:

For $n>0$:
$$
n^4−8n^3+24n^2−32n+16>n^4−8n^3−32n
$$

For $n>8$:
$$
n^4−8n^3−32n>n^4−9n^3
$$

So:
$$
\frac{243n^3−639n^2+865n−423}{n^4−8n^3+24n^2−32n+16}>\frac{244n^3}{n^4−9n^3}=\frac{244}{n−9}<\varepsilon
$$

Now it suffices to pick:
$$
n>244/\varepsilon+9
$$

Comment: Where did the $9n^3$ and $244n^3$ come from?

Comment: It's a rather arbitrary inequality: $n>8$ implies $n^2>64>32$ implies $n^3>32n$ implies $-32n>-n^3$  then summing $n^4-8n^3$ on both sides yields $n^4-8n^3-32>n^4-8n^3-n^3=n^4-9n^3$